# Rasbian can not mount WD external HDD at boot

Tags: hard-drive

I am very new to any sort of linux and just started to use raspberry pi 2 running on raspbian. I just attached my WD Passport Ultra through USB port, which is powered by rpi itself.

with command sudo fdsik -l, i am able to see

> /dev/sda

and

> /dev/sda1

parts of the hdd and when i try to mount it manually it works but the problem just arises when i try to modify /etc/fstab file. Due to fact that the hdd is in ntfs format i already installed ntfs-3g to and modified

> /etc/fstab

like this;

> /dev/sda1 /home/wd ntfs-3g defaults 0 0

after rebooting, hdd is not mounted to the path at boot.

Can anyone help me understand what the problem can be?

Comment: if you run mount /home/wd does it mount correctly? if so you jsut need to add the auto flag to fstab

Comment: Yes when I run mount /home/wd it mounts but unfortunately auto flad doesn't work for me either and as i know "defaults" also includes auto flag

Comment: without the drive attached what does "ls -al /home/wd" give you? And on that note, I have never tried mounting in a /home directory. Have you got a user called wd on the system? Are there any errors in /var/log/messages?

Comment: drwxrwxrw- 2 pi   pi   4096 Şub 19 17:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Şub 19 17:09 ..     That is what returned to ls -al /home/wd command there is no user called WD defined on the system but can't also auto-mount to any other paths too

Comment: unfortunately the answer here http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=48160 was "That's because ntfs uses a userspace driver, not a kernel driver so it can't mount until the last thing in the boot process.

Move your data, reformat as ext4, move your data back."

Comment: Thanks rob, seems reformatting as ext4 is the only solution

Comment: or try this. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27916/unable-to-connect-seagate-external-drive

Answer (score 3):

First, anytime you are trying to add an external drive in fstab, you need to be using a UUID. It is not wise to use /dev/ with external devices, as they might change.

```
sudo blkid
```

this will list you UUID

In /etc/fstab

```
UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxx /home/wd ntfs-3g defaults 0 0
```

This is likely to fix your issue, as it is separate from waiting for the devices to be listed under /dev/

UUID is addressable even from BIOS/boot loader.

Comment: Unfortunately writing down UUID instead of /dev/sda does not make any good.....

Comment: Hmm, sorry bud. This must be a new issue with the recent hardware/OS changes.

Comment: Try using TABs as opposed to spaces in your /etc/fstab.